# Android StudioでEmptyProjectをJavaで作成できない

Tags: java, android-studio

Android Studioをインストールしjavaで新規のプロジェクトを作成しようとしたのですが、empty activityで言語を選択する項目が表示されません。

参考にしたサイトでは選択するプルダウンリストが表示されていました。
他のテンプレートでは表示されます。
完全にアンインストールしてから再インストールしてみたりもしましたが表示されません
empty activityはjavaでは作成できないのでしょうか？

環境：
windows 11
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-25199 (build 11.0.12+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-25199 (build 11.0.12+7, mixed mode)
Android Studio 2022.2.1

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 参考にしたサイトで使用している Android Studio のバージョンも質問とまったく同じものでしょうか？ (バージョン違いによって画面構成が異なる可能性があります)

Comment: 確認したところバージョンは違いました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

記事と同じバージョンに下げたところ、表示されました。
Cubick様ありがとうございました。